# Rancher 2.5.5 failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled

Tags: docker, rancher

I installed the rancher in a single node via container docker. I have 03 etcd and control Plane hosts and 03 Worker hosts. I get this message on the Rancher GUI:

> This cluster is currently Unavailable; areas that directly interact with it will not be available until the API is ready.

This error is in the rancher container logs.

```
failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context cancel


2021/06/05 20:05:18 [ERROR] error syncing 'c-dbk7g': handler cluster-deploy: Get "https://192.168.0.153:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/cattle-system/daemonsets/cattle-node-agent": waiting for cluster [c-dbk7g] agent to connect, requeuing
2021-06-05 20:06:34.914592 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55883328
2021-06-05 20:06:34.957157 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55883328 (took 41.306809ms)
2021/06/05 20:07:07 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:07:07 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
W0605 20:07:33.746643      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:09:12 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:09:12 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
W0605 20:09:58.886016      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
W0605 20:10:27.733243      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:11:18 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:11:18 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021-06-05 20:11:34.920593 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55885185
2021-06-05 20:11:34.960779 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55885185 (took 38.698053ms)
2021/06/05 20:13:26 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:13:26 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021/06/05 20:15:39 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:15:39 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021-06-05 20:16:34.926857 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55887037
2021-06-05 20:16:34.967700 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55887037 (took 39.686485ms)
W0605 20:16:46.170323      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
W0605 20:17:23.630669      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:17:40 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:17:40 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
W0605 20:19:20.022226      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:19:52 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:19:52 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021-06-05 20:21:34.933216 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55888893
2021-06-05 20:21:34.973827 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55888893 (took 38.986348ms)
2021/06/05 20:21:45 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:21:45 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021/06/05 20:22:39 [ERROR] error syncing 'c-dbk7g': handler cluster-deploy: Get "https://192.168.0.153:6443/apis/apps/v1/namespaces/cattle-system/daemonsets/cattle-node-agent": waiting for cluster [c-dbk7g] agent to connect, requeuing
W0605 20:22:53.276338      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:23:36 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:23:36 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021/06/05 20:25:57 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:25:57 [ERROR] failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled
2021-06-05 20:26:34.940664 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55890751
2021-06-05 20:26:34.981048 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55890751 (took 38.961021ms)
W0605 20:26:40.871202      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:27:59 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:27:59 [ERROR] **failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled**
W0605 20:29:51.284898      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021/06/05 20:30:00 [INFO] Stopping cluster agent for c-dbk7g
2021/06/05 20:30:00 [ERROR] **failed to start cluster controllers c-dbk7g: context canceled**
W0605 20:30:08.914160      33 watcher.go:199] watch chan error: etcdserver: mvcc: required revision has been compacted
2021-06-05 20:31:34.947562 I | mvcc: store.index: compact 55892605
2021-06-05 20:31:34.986801 I | mvcc: finished scheduled compaction at 55892605 (took 38.106291m
```